# JQ - how to select field with condition that the field's value starts with another field's value

Tags: json, select, jq

Suppose I have a list of json items. Each item contains field `a` and `b`. I'd love to get a list of values of field `a` such that field `a`'s value starts with field `b`'s value. For example,

```
{
  "a": "1234",
  "b": "123"
},
{
  "a": "1234",
  "b": "12"
},
{
  "a": "foo",
  "b": "bar"
}
```

would result in

```
"1234",
"1234"
```

Is this achievable using jq?

Comment: Looking at your questions history https://stackoverflow.com/users/3773970/j20120307?tab=questions, you have not "accepted" answers to any of your questions. You should appreciate the efforts the authors are making to answer. See  [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your given input data, put in an array, you could use `startswith()` function as below. Your input JSON as such isn't quite valid, the objects needs to be enclosed within the array `[..]` for `jq` to operate on it.

```
jq '.[] | .b as $data | select(.a | startswith($data) ).a'
```

[jq playground](https://jqplay.org/s/yeFwP8HON4)

Or if you want to put the result in a CSV format, do

```
jq --raw-output '[.[] | .b as $data | select(.a | startswith($data) ).a] | @csv'
```